# how to export svg to png on the command line without antialiasing

Tags: svg, imagemagick, inkscape

I need to do some batch processing of svg files.  SVG elements are all either black or white and I need bitmap images that are monochrome (black/white, no grayscale).

From within the inkscape gui I can just select this as an option.

[image]

However, I don't see any inkscape cli options related to antialiasing

Same for librsvg, (rsvg-convert) no command line options in the manual related to anti-aliasing.

Second thought was to just export to a png image and then use ImageMagick to threshhold the image.  However, on my system

```
Mac OSX catalina (latest)
brew install imagemagick -> 7.0.10-23
```

when I run the following, i get an error:

```
>>> convert test.im.png -channel RGB -threshhold 50% test.im.t.png
convert: unrecognized option `-threshhold' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3112.
```

looking for a little help on how to get from a black and white svg to a black and white png on the command line for batch processing given these problems.

Comment: You misspelled threshold. It is 'threshold' not 'threshhold'

Comment: wow... I misspelled threshold... I don't know what to say.  time for the walk of shame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IM 7, use magick, not convert. So try

```
magick +antialias image.svg -channel RGB result.png
```

or

```
magick image.svg -channel RGB -threshold 50% result.png
```

If one of these works, then you can process a whole folder of files using magick mogrify. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: without the `-channel RGB`, the blacks get converted to transparency.  The +antialias seems to have no effect in this case

Comment: Your SVG file must have an alpha channel. To properly turn it off use `-alpha off` or `-channel RGB` is also OK. +antialias might not work. I do not know if there is a command to properly turn off anti-aliasing when reading SVG files other than turning it off inside the SVG file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this will be added in version 1.4 of inkscape, which as of now (March 2024) needs to be compiled manually. It's not in the linux ppa 1.3 version yet either.

Have compiled and tested, works well.

The new `--export-png-antialias` command line option, which you can set to 0 (none) to 3 (best)

Here is the source code showing the new version:

https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/actions/actions-output.cpp?ref_type=heads#L315

Comment: amazing how new answers can come in years later